# Function seems to break when passed callback value, even though callback returns ok

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm writing a (non-commercial) book cataloging web application for a school, and the data about the books comes from two different sources: Google Books and Openlibrary.org.  Google is more reliable, so I only rely on Openlibrary for library-style subject headings, which Google does not supply.

I get the ISBN of the books from Google's api using `$.getJSON`, within which I callback to `$.get`, which calls a php script that uses `curl` to get around cross-domain rules and call the Openlibrary api using the Google-obtained ISBN as a parameter.  This `$.get` passes the result from Openlibrary to a callback called `printboxes(result)` that uses the data from Google and OpenLibrary together to print some pre-populated HTML form fields, which can then be used to submit to a database.  Sound more complicated than it needs to be?  Maybe it is.

The structure of this page is a search form where multiple books can be searched in a row (usually by scanning in their isbns) in one go, making a kind of super-form with a nested-array name structure, and then they can all be submitted at once.  Originally, I had the individual book boxes `.append`ing to a single main `<div>` within the `<form>`.  Then I decided I wanted to have the searches `.prepend`, such that whatever the last book scanned was, it would appear at the top of the form so you could see it right away and make sure everything was kosher.  This worked okay, but if the person selected that they wanted more than one result per search, then the results would stack up 54321 per search, rather than 12345.  What I wanted was for the searches to stack 54321 on the page, but within each search, the results should appear 12345.  So I caused another `<div id=\"searchcount\""+scount+">` to be `.prepend`ed to the main form with each search, and then I `.append`ed each individual result to `$('#searchcount'+scount)`.  This proved a step too far, and the `printboxes(result)` callback breaks.

Examining the network activity showed that all the `$.get`s were returning accurate results.  If I call `printboxes` outside of the last callback to Openlibrary, and just pass it a manual value plus what it gets from Google, it works, `.append`s, `.prepend`s and all.  If I call `alert(result)` within the callback to Openlibrary, that works.  If I go one DOM element shallower, i.e. back to the configuration that skipped `.prepend`ing the per-search divs and just printed the results in their own divs, it works.

But when it goes like this:

```
function printboxes(sub)
               {
                var subjects = sub;
               //subjects represents the return string from the curl request to Openlibrary
               $('#searchcount'+scount).append("<div class=\"resultbox\" id=\"results"+scount+''+i+"\">"+(i+1)+".</div>")
                .append("Title: <input class=volumevalue size=50 type=text name=\"volumeinfo["+scount+"]["+i+"][booktitle]\" readonly='readonly' value=\"" + btitle + "\" /><br>")
                .append("Author: <input class=volumevalue size=50 type=text name=\"volumeinfo["+scount+"]["+i+"][bookauthor]\" value=\"" + bauthor + "\" /><br>")
                .append("Subjects: <input name =\"volumeinfo["+scount+"]["+i+"][subjects]\" type='text' size=100 value = \""+subjects+"\" /></br>");
//I realize these element names are outrageous, but they're necessary for parsing the form later.
                if (i===0)
                    {
                    //This if statement automatically selects the first result of a given search for insertion in the database.
                    document.getElementsByName("volumeinfo["+scount+"][0]['checker']")[0].setAttribute('checked','true');
                    }

                //this recursive function down here is necessary because looping structures wouldn't sync with ajax calls.  It loops over the results from Google books, parsing the JSON as it goes for use here populating most of the values in printboxes.
                geterator(i+i, countdown-1, stack);
                }

$.get('./subcurl.php', {bookkey: isbn}, function(result){   
                      //Get subjects with curl from openlibrary and pass the result to printboxes.
                      printboxes(result);


                    });//end curl request 
               }
```

It gets all out of whack.  My only hint from the console as to why is that when the if statement to check the first search result's box, it complains that `document.getElementsByName("volumeinfo[0][0]['checker']")[0]` is undefined, and therefore its attributes can't be set.  If I comment out the `if` statement, then I get no such error from the console, and the network requests go through fine, but the DOM stops appending at `<div id = "searchcount0">`, and none of the results show on the page.  Again, everything works fine if I go one DOM element shallower, (i.e. no 'searchcount' div, just one big div for all the results).  It also works fine if I use `printboxes` with a hard-coded parameter outside of the callback, but it seems I can't be both two divs deep and also have the callback function properly.

Help me StackObiwan, you're my only hope.

Comment: For best results, consider trimming your question to include the fewest details required to describe the problem. We will ask for more details if needed, but this amount of text is often limits the number and quality of responses received.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle of the problem?

Comment: This might not be the problem, but your html strings are missing quotations around some of the property values.  Perhaps that is screwing up the DOM?

Comment: Where is the element named `...checker`? The function `printboxes` doesn't add one at least. Consider creating your element properly instead of just using strings to append (i.e. `document.createElement('input'); input.name = foo;` etc.)